# How to add custom rules to a calculator?

Tags: javascript, random, combinations, permutation, calculator

I'm making a outfit randomizer. But I would like to add some rules to it to prevent weird outfits like a white tie on a white shirt. Or any tie on a graphic tee. Or wearing a turtleneck over a shirt.

This is the code, so far:

```
        var shirts = ["White", "navy", "light blue", "gray"];
        var pants = ["black", "navy", "gray"];
        var ties = ["red and blue squares", "purple", "white", "red"];

        var random_shirt = shirts[Math.floor(Math.random()*shirts.length)];
        var random_pants = pants[Math.floor(Math.random()*pants.length)];
        var random_tie = ties[Math.floor(Math.random()*ties.length)];

        document.write( " shirt: " + random_shirt + " pants: " + random_pants + " tie: " + random_tie);
```

I know it's done with if's and else's, but I don't know how.

Please forgive my JS illiteracy. I learned it but never actually used it. Until now.

Thanks

Comment: Just FYI: You cannot shout out to specific users here. The @ notation only works if someone has commented or posted to this specific question or answer to this question first and you're responding to them. It doesn't work if someone has commented or posted on a different question (yours or anyone else's).

Answer (score 1):

There are severals ways of doing this, this is my suggestion:

You can filter the pants array based on the result of random shirt

```
var random_shirt = [random logic];

/* 
   This will iterate over your pants array, returning a filtered array 
   with containing the items that returned true
     item: the actual item
     index: index of the actual item
     array: original array
*/ 
filtered_pants = pants.filter(function(item, index, array) {
  if (item == random_shirt) {
    // This item won't be in the filtered array
    return false;
  } 
  if ([another custom rule]) {
    return false;
  }
  /* 
    After passing all the rules return true to include this item in 
    the filtered array
  */
  return true;

});

// Now shuffle over the filtered array
var random_pants = filtered_pants[Math.floor(Math.random()*pants.length)];
```

Then just repeat it with the tie

Make sure to learn the documentation for the filter method ->
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Alternatively you can use the reduce method which is similar -> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce

If you don't quite understand these methods, watch this playlist, it'll help a lot -> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BMUiFMZr7vk&list=PL0zVEGEvSaeEd9hlmCXrk5yUyqUag-n84